# SwiftUI - FatalError: Index Out Of Range when Accepting Sheets that are supposed to decline in count

Tags: swiftui

I have a pop-up sheet in a SwiftUI app that is supposed to allow me to accept invitations to any new groups I can belong to - the pop-up sheet is a tab view that allows me to swipe between all my different invitations, and they disappear as I either accept or decline them.

However, I get a crash in the `@main` line of my app whenever I accept or decline the final invitation.

This invitation sheet has a view model with a property that is an array of all my pending invitations. It constructs a tabView with a tab for each of the pending invitations. The sheet view has a "sheetCount" state variable that is supposed to decrease as invitations get accepted, and then dismiss the sheet once the sheet count reaches zero.

I suspect what is happening is the pending invitations are decreasing to zero before the sheetCount reaches zero, and there's some issue trying to render it with no tabs available, and this is causing the crash. But the crash error seems non-specific:

```
2021-11-05 08:59:07.036721-0400 GoalTogether[748:24652] [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x1052d2800 Disabling recursion trigger logging
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
2021-11-05 08:59:29.996209-0400 GoalTogether[748:24652] Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to construct this code flow so that the sheetCount directly follows the number of pendingInvitations and dismisses the sheet as soon as the last pendingViewModel is removed from the property?

Here is the pop-up sheet that takes all my `pendingInviteViewModels` in the `groupHubViewModel` and constructs the tab view of invitations for each each pending invite.

```
struct PendingGroupsSheet: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var groupHubVM: GroupHubViewModel
    
    @State var sheetCount: Int
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    init(groupHubVM: GroupHubViewModel) {
        self.groupHubVM = groupHubVM
        
        self._sheetCount = State(initialValue: groupHubVM.pendingInviteViewModels.count)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(groupHubVM.pendingInviteViewModels) { singleGroupVM in
                PendingGroupInviteView(singleGroupVM: singleGroupVM, onAcceptDecline: {
                    self.dismissIfEmpty()
                })
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
    
    func dismissIfEmpty() {
        sheetCount -= 1
        if sheetCount > 0 {
            return
        } else {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

The TabView has these pending group invite views, which have buttons for accept and decline:

```
                Button(action: {
                    self.onAcceptDecline()
                    do {
                        try singleGroupVM.declineGroupInvitation()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }){
                    Text("Decline")
                }.buttonStyle(RoundedRectangleBlackButtonStyle())
                .padding()
```

Either of those buttons is supposed to accept or decline an invitation, which will decrease the number of `pendingInviteViewModels` within the main `groupHubViewModel` for this page, using the `dismissIfEmpty` function within the sheet.

Once the last one is declined or accepted, the dismissIfEmpty function should be setting the sheetCount to 0, and dismissing the sheet. But I think something is happening where the pendingViewModels must be getting set to 0 or nil before the sheetCount decreases, and then I think that is causing the error.

Comment: You have created to sources of truth here as I see it. I would suggest removing the `@State` property in the view and only use the view model to keep track of the count

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson - the only issue I'm having with that is that the code flow that causes the number of view models to drop does not automatically cause the function to run that checks the count and dismisses the sheet if it's dropped to zero. I've found another solution that seems to be working, but still has the two sources of truth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue was caused by having an empty TabView. There seems to be a gap between when the invite is accepted and when the sheetCount causes the sheet to disappear, during which I have an empty TabView.

If I wrap the TabView in an if statement that confirms the count of pendingInviteViewModels is at least one, this fixes the issue:

```
        if groupHubVM.pendingInviteViewModels.count >= 1 {
            TabView {
                ForEach(groupHubVM.pendingInviteViewModels) { singleGroupVM in
                    PendingGroupInviteView(singleGroupVM: singleGroupVM, onAcceptDecline: {
                        self.dismissIfEmpty()
                    })
                }
            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
```